# Add or Remove form text field and labels dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a code here to add form text fields dynamically. However, I needed to add the label to the text field and each time a new text field is added, the label also changes value, for example, increment by one. I have managed to add the labels but my main problem is:
1. How to get the label increment by one every time a new field and label are added
2. Be able to remove the label as well when the text field is removed.
I am new to Javascript so a detailed explanation would so welcome.

Javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
        var y = 2;
        var labelHTML = '<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-4 control-label">'+ $y + '</label>';
        var fieldHTML = '<div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
        var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
        $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
            if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                x++; //Increment field counter
                $(wrapper).append(labelHTML, fieldHTML); // Add field html
                y++;
            }
        });
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
            x--; //Decrement field counter
        });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML Code:

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question Options:</legend>
        <div class="field_wrapper form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-4 control-label">1</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to define your html inside your add function to make them unique to each other.

Second you need to remove the `label` before you remove the input field and his parent div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
        var y = 2;
        var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
        
        var labelHTML = "";
        var fieldHTML = "";
        
        $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
            if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                labelHTML = '<label for="inputEmail' + x + '" class="col-md-4 control-label">'+ 'test' + '</label>';
                fieldHTML = '<div class="col-md-6"><input id="inputEmail' + x + '" type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
            
                x++; //Increment field counter
                $(wrapper).append(labelHTML, fieldHTML); // Add field html
                y++;
            }
        });
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').prev().remove(); //Remove previous field html
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
            x--; //Decrement field counter
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Question Options:</legend>
    <div class="field_wrapper form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-4 control-label">1</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="inputEmail" type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Wow @Brent Boden, it simply worked like a charm, I only replaced the 'test' attribute in the labelHTML in the javascript code and the code is now working fine. Thanks so much.

Comment: @user2978051 Please mark this answer as the correct one